# MIN array function non zeros only

Tags: excel

I have been trying to get this array function to output (non-zero) minimum values in the 'FINAL DATA'  AE column.  Can you see a structural error in this formula?

```
       =IF($C$4="All EMEA",

MIN(IF('FINAL DATA'!$2:$AE$250000<>0,

('FINAL DATA'!$J$2:$J$250000=$C$4)*('FINAL DATA'!$E$2:$E$250000=$E$4)*( 'FINAL DATA'!$AE$2:$AE$250000))),

MIN(IF('FINAL DATA'!$AE$2:$AE$250000<>0, 

('FINAL DATA'!$K$2:$K$250000=$C$4)*('FINAL DATA'!$E$2:$E$250000=$E$4)*( 'FINAL DATA'!$AE$2:$AE$250000)))

)
```

Answer (score 2):

By using <>0 that will eliminate zeroes and blanks, so that isn't the problem.....[although if you only want to eliminate blanks and have zero as a valid return value you should use **<>""**]

You can't multiply the conditions with the number range because by multiplying you get zeroes for any rows where the conditions are not satisfied, use multiple IFs instead, like this:

`=MIN(IF('FINAL DATA'!$AE$2:$AE$250000<>0,IF('FINAL DATA'!$J$2:$J$250000=$C$4,IF('FINAL DATA'!$E$2:$E$250000=$E$4,'FINAL DATA'!$AE$2:$AE$250000))))`

Answer (score 1):

Second line, you have !$2, no column specified.

MIN(IF('FINAL DATA'**!$2**:$AE$250000<>0,

Also, it looks like you are trying to run a single If comparison against a range, which I don't think will work the way you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Barry has identified the core problem (tests returnimg 0 to the MIN function).

Here's a refactor of your formula (still an array formula) that solves this, and is quite a bit shorter

```
=MIN(IF(($S:$S<>0)*($E:$E=$E$4)*(IF($C$4="All EMEA",$J:$J,$K:$K)=$C$4),
 ($S:$S)))
```

Note that this (as would your original formaul, when fixed) will return `0` if there are no qualifying values >0 in the ranges

Comment: +1 Chris - To make it clearer if there are no qualifying values you could use SMALL instead of MIN (with k = 1), which would generate an error [#NUM!] instead of zero - wrap whole thing in IFERROR to generate some sort of text error if required.....

Comment: I didn't know about SMALL, and this worked like an absolute charm. Its brother LARGE was what I ended up using for a similar use case. Thanks a trillion!

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the zeros by using an `IF()` function in an array formula.  Consider the following:

```
       A
Row  -----
 1       0
 2       7
 3       5
 4       6
 5        
 6       3
```

The array formula `=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$6>0,$A$1:$A$6))` will return `3` because the `0` and blank cell are eliminated with the `>0` portion of the if statement.

Comment: This portion of my code was meant to have this role:              IF('FINAL DATA'!$2:$AE$250000<>0, .....  )  However, there actually no zeros in this column.. they are BLANK.   So is my first formula correct and in the case of blanks, I might use the NOT(ISBLANK formulae..

Comment: A blank cell evaluate to `0`, so using `>0` you can eliminate blank cells too.  I revised the example to demonstrate this.